# Data is not showing up in html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am running into a issue with showing the data from my variable, itemListPrice. I have checked in the console and the data is populated into the itemListPrice, but its not showing up in my html, am I loading it all wrong?

Here is the markup

```
<div id="app2">
    <div id="TableContainer" style="width:798px !important">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Catalog Name</label></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ currentCatalogName }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Item Name</label></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td> {{ itemPriceList.Name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><label>Item List</label></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="575px">${{ itemPriceList.ItemListPrice }}</td>
                        <td>${{ itemPriceList.ItemListPrice }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><label>Item Features</label></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <template v-for="item in itemPriceList.ItemFeatures">
                        <tr v-if="item.FeatureQuantity != 0">
                            <td width="250px">{{ item.FeatureName }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.FeatureQuantity }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Item IAM</label></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ itemPriceList.ItemIAM }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my code

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app2',
    beforeCreate: function () {
        StartBusyIndicator("#ItemPriceListWindow");
    },
    created: function () {
        this.GetItemDetails();
    },
    mounted: function () {
        StopBusyIndicator("#ItemPriceListWindow");
    },
    data: {
        itemPriceList: [],
        orderItems: currentOrderItems,
        currentCatalogName: currentCatalog,
        priceList: null
    },
    methods: {
        GetItemDetails: function () {
            TryCatch(function() {
                let result = GetItemPriceDetails();
                this.itemPriceList = result;
                priceList = result;
            });
        },
        GetOrderItems: function () {

        },
        OptionPriceSplitter: function (optionprice) {
            return TryCatch(function() {
                let sentenceSplit = optionprice.split('& ');
                let comp = '';

                for (let i = 0; i < sentenceSplit.length; i++) {
                    comp += sentenceSplit[i] + '\n';
                }
                return sentenceSplit;
            });
        },
        GlobalListPriceCalculation: function (globalgroupid) {
            return TryCatch(function() {
                let listPrice = 0.00;
                let priceList = this.itemPriceList;
                let result = priceList.GlobalListPrices.filter(function(item) {
                    if (item.GlobalGroupID == globalgroupid) {
                        listPrice = listPrice + item.Price;
                    }
                });

                if (listPrice == 0) {
                    listPrice = "";
                } else {
                    listPrice = "$" + listPrice.toFixed(2);
                }
                return listPrice;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what does `TryCatch` do ?

Comment: @birdspider Thats just a custom Try Catch statement for errors

Comment: does `TryCatch` bind `this` to its callback?  otherwise they have no access to `this` - and please tell me you don't ignore the `catch(e){}` errors in your custom `TryCatch`

Comment: @birdspider, i removed the custom trycatch and everything worked. The errors get emailed to me when there is an error. If you want to post as answer with an explanation then I'll be more than happy to mark as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `TryCatch(cb)` is something along the lines of

```
function TryCatch(cb){ let x = null; try { x = cb() } catch(e) {} return x; }
```

you *loose* 2 important things:

- `this` (you could bind it via `cb.call(this)`)
- utterly usefull error messages

---

furher points:

> I have checked in the console

checkout the excellent browser plugin for ff and chrome [vue-devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd)

> itemPriceList = []

you initalize `itemPriceList` as array, use it as array `item in itemPriceList`, but also use it as object `{{ itemPriceList.Name }}` - what shall it be ?